# Single App Link handled by multiple build flavours

Tags: android, google-play, applinks

I am working on android application that needs to have App Links support. However the application will have multiple flavors and there is a chance that end users will have multiple flavors installed on their mobile phones at the same time.

The application will need to support App Links, however the same links needs to be handled by all of the build flavors. 
So, for example, given a link A, if user has two applications installed: X and Y, both of the applications should be able to handle link A.

This scenario works fine, as when **assetlinks.json** is configured correctly to support multiple application flavors and user has multiple versions of the application installed on his device, then upon accessing the link a prompt is displayed, asking user which application to use for given link.

**The question would be if Google Play will have issues with multiple flavors of the application being uploaded to Play Store, declaring intent filters that handle exactly the same app links or app links schemas?**

There is no clarification about it in the Google Documentation, except [google docs](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations):

> Different apps may handle links for different resources under the same web host. For example, app1 may declare an intent filter for https://example.com/articles, and app2 may declare an intent filter for https://example.com/videos.

which suggest that different apps **may** but not **must** declare a different intent filter.